# initialize field in method

Tags: c++, class, object

New to c++ from javascript.
I'm used to initializing new properties of an object inside its methods. For instance:

```
var object = {
    setVariables: function() {
        this.arrayLength = 4;
        this.array = [];
        for(var i=0; i<this.arrayLength; i++) {
            this.array[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

So I am setting a property in terms of another property.

But with c++,

```
class Object = {
    int arrayLength;
    int array[arrayLength];
}
```

I can't initialize the array until I know its length which I can't set until I use a constructor or a method. If I try to do this with a method...

```
class Object = {
    public:
    void setVariables() {
        this->array[4]; /* this doesn't fly because I haven't initialized the array and I can't initialize until I know its length /*
    }
}
```

I also can't use a constructor because a constructor simply sets the fields, but doesn't initialize them from what I've read.

This is just an example of what i'm generally confused about which is how to set and initialize an object's fields in terms of its other fields. If its confusing what i'm trying to do, take this concrete example:

**I want to initialize and set an 'arrayLength' field of an object, and then initialize an array field of that object using that length value. How would I do this?**

**Or if someone could tell me how to initialize an object's fields inside its methods that would solve the problem**

Comment: Constructors *should* initialize fields. If they aren't you're doing it wrong. Anyway, variable length arrays are not standard C++ and you can initialize members where they're declared.

Comment: beware, what you've written is at the moment not yet compilable c++. The container you might be searching for is the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: `class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
};

Rectangle::Rectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = a;
  height = b;
}`

Comment: That above is an example of what i've seen for a constructor, and it doesn't seem to initialize/declare width or height, but just set them.

Comment: The actual problem here seems to be that the "simple" array declaration in C++ doesn't allow the length to be set at runtime. There are two typical ways to do what you want; see answer by @Ranic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about learning C++ the hard way. C++, despite its similar syntax, is not at all like javascript (or java or C# for that matter).

In C++ you define your class, and the class constructors build the object in memory, setting the member variables to the values desired. You **must** use a constructor to do what you want to do. From the code you've shown, it looks like you're trying to re-implement `std::vector`.

```
class object
{
    int   m_size;   // size of the array
    int * m_array;  // pointer to the array

    public:
    // this is the constructor
    // it initializes m_size to the value of size
    // it allocates an array of int on the heap, and initializes 
    // the m_array pointer to the address of that array, then 
    // initializes each entry in the array 
    object( int size ) : m_size( size ), m_array( new int[size] )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i ) 
        { 
            m_array[i] = i;
        }
    }

    // this is the destructor; it is **very** important
    // this frees the dynamically allocated array when the
    // object instance is destroyed
    ~object()
    {
        delete [] m_array;
    }

    int operator[]( int index ) const
    {
        if ( index < 0 || index >= m_size ) throw std::range_error();
        return m_array[ index ];
    }
    int & operator[]( int index ) 
    {
        if ( index < 0 || index >= m_size ) throw std::range_error();
        return m_array[ index ];
    }
};


object o(5);
o[1] = 99;
int v = o[1];
```

Not guaranteed to be 100% correct- I didn't compile it, and you shouldn't use this anyway. That's what `std::vector` and `std::array` are for.

I strongly recommend you get a good C++ book, maybe *Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*, and read it. You will be much more successful.

Comment: Your code is helpful. I thought I could just learn a new syntax and I'd be fine but this is a whole other animal. Thanks for the book rec, I just ordered it.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically allocate the array by declaring it as `int* array;` and then, in the constructor, doing `array = new int[arrayLength];`. Or you can use a `vector`, which you can resize whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your variables inside class, C++ doesn't allow initialization unless your variable is a const or static. For example, you cannot initialize

```
class foo{
int x = 10; 
};
```

Inside your function, You can initialize a 1-dimensional array in C++ by simply using

```
int x[10](); // <-- initialize to 0, use x[10](y) to initialize to y.
```

For dynamic arrays, you can construct them dynamically in constructor and destruct them in destuctor. 
For example

```
class foo{    
    int *array;     
    int arraySize;
    foo(int size){   
        arraySize=size;
        array = new int[arraySize];  //constructs array with the dynamic size
                                       //don't forget to throw them away    
    }
    ~foo(){      
        delete array;    
    } 
}
```

There are easier ways to implement dynamic array in STL (vector) and 0x, but this is how classic C++ handles this issue.

Comment: Thanks. The 'new' operator seems key. I'll use that.